# Adding Telerik Datepicker to Dynamically added form fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, datepicker

I have a scenario where I have to dynamically add fields on the page through JavaScript.

How can I apply telerik datepicker to dynamically added fields?

I'm using telerik extensions for ASP.net MVC 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this (make sure the [required javascript](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-required-javascript-files.html) files are included):

```
$("<input />").appendTo(document.body).tDatePicker();
```

Comment: @Atnas what can i pass to this method so dates are generated according to UK format. By default its generating dates in US format

Comment: never mind its `$('.telerik-dp').tDatePicker({ format: 'dd/MM/yyyy'});`. don't you think client part of Telerik is poorly documented?

Comment: You have probably missed this: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-datepicker-globalization.html

Comment: i was exactly looking at this one before i posted the comment but i could not find passing options to tDatePikcer in this doc

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for creating a `DatePicker` dynamically

```
var dp = @Html.Telerik().DatePicker().Name("DateCreated").InputHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "FilterDatePicker" });

$("#body").append(dp);

$('.FilterDatePicker').tDatePicker();
```